# Adding Video in MVc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC  I want to know how to add Video in MVC 2.0 using Html5. when I try to add video in Mvc like this

Video src="http://stelllent/Videos/Mvc"

It display error Video tag is not defined.

Comment: and... give some more context and the rendered html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first prerequisite is to have a browser which supports the [`<video>`](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) tag (IE 9.0+, FireFox 3.5+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 3.0+, Opera 10.5+, iPhone 1.0+, Android 2.0+, ...). Then you could use it like this:

```
<video src="/videos/movie.avi" controls="controls">
    Your browser does not support the video tag
</video>
```

Or if you have a controller action which is streaming the video you could also point the `src` attribute to it.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov , sir i am using the same but it is not playing in chrome , but working fine in firefox .. any suggestion .

<video src="~/Media/@item.Content" style="width:115px; height:75px;" controls>
                </video>